# How to match 0 or 1 time character at the end of line?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to normalize a URL, to extract the content after `://` and before the last `/` at the end of line if it exists.

Here is my script:

```
url = "https://example.com/25194425/"
matchUrl = re.findall(r'://(.*)/?$', url)
print matchUrl
```

What I want is `example.com/25194425`, but I get `example.com/25194425/`. How to deal with the last `/`?
Why doesn't `/?` work?

Comment: [`://(.*?)\/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/rX6eS8/1) Extract first captured group.

Comment: `/?` is not working because `/` needs to be **escaped** like this `\/`.

Comment: @noob. No it doesn't - `/` is not a special character, so escaping it will make no difference to the OPs original example. Maybe you're thinking of javascript, or something?

Comment: For url like `https://example.com/25194425`, what do you want to match?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to do it without using regex is using `urlparse`

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> url = 'https://example.com/25194425/'
>>> '{url.netloc}{url.path}'.format(url=urlparse(url)).rstrip('/')
'example.com/25194425'
```

Later on, if you want to include the protocol, port, params, ... parts into the normalized url. It can be done easier (than updating the regex)

```
>>> '{url.scheme}://{url.netloc}{url.path}'.format(url=urlparse(url)).rstrip('/')
'https://example.com/25194425'
```

Comment: in fact one should resist `re` for URL parsing because this makes code non-portable to Windows. Also your snipplet should use at least `os.path.sep`, or even better https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath right away. Nevertheless, this is the best answer-

Answer (score 1):

As one of the commenters [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737938/how-to-match-0-or-1-time-character-at-the-end-of-line#comment59149920_35737938), you just need to make the quantifier non-greedy:

```
://(.*?)/?$
```

However, the result of `findall()` is a list, not a string.  In this case it's list with only one entry, but it's still a list.  To get the actual string, you need to provide the index:

```
url = "https://example.com/25194425/"
match = re.findall(r'://(.*?)/?$', url)
print match[0]
```

But that seems like an inappropriate use of `findall()` to me.  I would have gone with `search()`:

```
url = "https://example.com/25194425/"
match = re.search(r'://(.*?)/?$', url)
if match:
    print match.group(1)
```

Comment: great, I understand better the greedy search now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default is possible because the regular match more characters. So '(.*) /' will match to the last slash.
You can use it:

```
matchUrl = re.findall(r'://(.*)/[^/]?$', url)
```

Comment: Fails if there's no trailing "/".

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Please try the following pattern (python 2.7x):

```
import re
url1 = 'https://example.com/25194425?/'
url2 = 'https://example.com/25194425?'
print re.findall('https?://([\S]+)(?<!/)[/]?', url1)
print re.findall('https?://([\S]+)(?<!/)[/]?', url2)
```

Output:

```
['example.com/25194425?']
['example.com/25194425?']
```

Thanks @Alan Moore for pointing out the word boundary issue. Now it should work for both scenarios.

Comment: This works for the OP's example because the last character (or last before the trailing slash) happens to be a word character.  You can't count on that being true in general.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Thanks for that!